# create or rename dynamic table teradata

Tags: teradata

I want to create or rename table with current_date.

For example:

1) create table TABLENAME || CURRENT_DATE

2) rename TABLE_NAME TO TABLE_NAME_||CURRENT_DATE.

How can I do it? Could you give an example?

Comment: Table name can't be dynamic without either Dynamic SQL (in a Stored Procedure) or a client variable, see https://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/Dynamic-Table-Name/td-p/42778

Answer (score 2):

This will append the current date in YYYYMMDD format to the table name. If YYYYMMDD is already appended to the name it's replaced with the new date.

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE rename_table_yyyymmdd
(
  IN db_name VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET Unicode,
  IN tbl_name VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET Unicode, -- defaults to current database
  OUT msg VARCHAR(600) CHARACTER SET Unicode
) SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
   DECLARE old_name VARCHAR(261)  CHARACTER SET Unicode; 
   DECLARE new_name VARCHAR(261)  CHARACTER SET Unicode;

   DECLARE sql_stmt VARCHAR(600)  CHARACTER SET Unicode;

   SET old_name  = '"' || Coalesce(db_name,DATABASE) || '"."' 
                       || Coalesce(tbl_name, '') || '"';

   SET new_name  = '"' || Coalesce(db_name,DATABASE) || '"."' 
                                -- remove an  existing "_YYYYMMDD" at the end of the table name
                       || Coalesce(RegExp_Replace(tbl_name, '_[0-9]{8}$'),'')    
                       || '_' || To_Char(Current_Date, 'yyyymmdd') || '"';

   SET sql_stmt = 'RENAME TABLE ' || old_name || ' AS ' || new_name || ';'; 

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;

   SET msg = 'Table ' || old_name || ' renamed to ' || new_name;

END;

CALL rename_table_yyyymmdd('myDB', 'tablename', msg);
CALL rename_table_yyyymmdd(null, 'tablename', msg);
```

No error handling, simply fails on errors, e.g. when you run it twice a day or the table doesn't exists or the user has no Drop Table right, etc.

Comment: Your answer helped me yet again to solve the dynamic naming issue. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

Step 1:

```
create table dat
(
saledate CURRENT_DATE
)
```

Step 2:

```
CREATE TABLE database.new_table AS
database.dat WITH DATA;
You can use sysdate or getdate to get current date.
```

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE` should be part of the table name.